# How to remove yum repositories

Tags: redhat, rpm, yum

*(This seems to be a rather straightforward question but I can't find the answer on SOF. Let me know if I missed a post and I will delete this!)*

Hello! How to delete the repositories that are listed in `yum repolist`?

For example, when I ran `yum reoplist`, I got (for example):

`repo id                   repo name
pgdg93/7Server/x86_64     PostgreSQL 9.3 7Server - x86_64`

But `man yum` does not tell me how to remove the repo if they are no longer in use (e.g. ). I tried `sudo yum-config-manager --disable pgdg93/7Server/x86_64` but the result of `yum repolist` is the same. Btw, this repo is installed through `rpm install [url]`

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

It's either a file in `/etc/yum.repos.d/` (new way) or an entry in `/etc/yum.conf` (old way). See https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/sec-Configuring_Yum_and_Yum_Repositories.html for details.

Answer (score -1):

We have multiple ways to do the same.

1. You may be able to go into `/etc/yum.repos.d/` and remove the file corresponding to the repository.
2. You can also try to remove the repo  and add with yum-config-manager

```
yum-config-manager --disable repository

yum-config-manager --add-repo http://www.example.com/example.repo
```

3. You can temporarily remove/disable a yum repo by adding the --disablerepo=(repo name) to your yum line.

```
yum --disablerepo=some-repository install some-package
```